# How to change PyQt4 window background image every specified number of seconds

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I would like to know how to set a background image for my PyQt4 window and then have it change, say, every 5 seconds.

Comment: [First result on google](http://codeprogress.com/python/libraries/pyqt/showPyQTExample.php?index=424&key=QMainWindowBackgroundImage)

Comment: how to make it change on the other image each 5 seconds

Comment: Use a thread with a loop which updates the image then sleeps for 5 seconds.

Comment: @lonewaft-'first result on google' that does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little example to achieve what you want:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import os
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib


class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, path_list):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.init_ui(path_list)

    def init_ui(self, path_list):
        self.palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt test")
        self.resize(800, 600)

        self.load_list_backgrounds(path_list)
        self.change_background()

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(5000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.change_background)
        self.timer.start()

        self.show()

    def load_list_backgrounds(self, path_list):
        self.list_pixmaps = [QtGui.QPixmap(p) for p in path_list]
        self.list_brushes = [QtGui.QBrush(l.scaled(self.size(), QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio))
                             for l in self.list_pixmaps]

        self.index_image = 0

    def change_background(self):
        print 'tick'
        self.palette.setBrush(
            QtGui.QPalette.Background, self.list_brushes[self.index_image % len(self.list_brushes)])
        self.setPalette(self.palette)
        self.index_image += 1


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.addLibraryPath(
        os.path.join(get_python_lib(), "PyQt4", "plugins"))
    print QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()

    home_path = os.path.expanduser('~')
    ex = Example([
        os.path.join(home_path, 'Desktop', 'test.jpg'),
        os.path.join(home_path, 'Desktop', 'test1.jpg'),
        os.path.join(home_path, 'Desktop', 'test2.jpg')
    ])

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Few notes to consider:

- Maybe you don't need to add the pyqt plugins path manually
- The brushes are scaled accordingly to the QMainWindow's size, if that's not what you want check the [docs of the scaled method](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpixmap.html#scaled-2)

Comment: what do you mean by 'hardcoded' ? here what my code to list jpgs looks like 
`for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):`
     `if f.endswith(".jpg"):`
          `print(f)`

Comment: @jaisenberg I've edited my answer so now you can send your list of images to the widget from the client. If the answer helped you out, please consider mark it as valid. Interesting question btw, it was fun ;)

Comment: The programm works great, but there was an issue with loading images - I just had black screen; it was fixed. Please, change the code to the [following](http://pastebin.com/S2dwyAXv) in case others have this problem too. Without doubt this is the best answer.